# R, control the order to populate an array in base R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Say I have a list of 3x2 matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
m2 <- matrix(7:12, nrow = 3)
m3 <- matrix(13:18, nrow = 3)
m4 <- matrix(19:24, nrow = 3)
x <- list(m1,m2,m3,m4)
```

If I want a 4x3x2 array I can use the `abind` package as:

```
a <- abind::abind(x, along = 0)
```

Here, `dim(a)` is as required and the first index element is my original `m1`

```
identical(a[1,,], m1)
[1] TRUE
```

How can I populate an array the same way in base R (do not ask why) ? I thought this would do it (but no!):

```
A <- array(unlist(x), dim = c(length(x), nrow(x[[1]]), ncol(x[[1]]) ) )
identical(A[1,,], m1)
[1] FALSE
```

Will `aperm` enable me to tweak the array ?

Comment: How about a good ol' `for` loop? `for (i in seq_along(x)) A[i,,]<-x[[i]]` (after having properly initialized `A`).

Comment: With `aperm`: `aperm(array(unlist(x),c(dim(x[[1]]),length(x))),c(3,1,2))`.

Comment: Spot on! I tried but think I did not understand the aperm along parameter.

Comment: @nicola: You're welcome to turn the comment into an answer